# Hub and spoke peered VNETs and Loadbalancer

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I have a hub and spoke topology of peered vnets. I wanted to place a loadbalancer in the hub and have all outbound traffic from each VM via a single public IP.

The portal and API suggest that load balancer doesnt support multiple peered vnets.

Has anybody solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a VM in a peered vNet behind a load balancer in another vNet. If your aim is to get a consistent private IP across all vNet's then at the moment the only solution (native, not third party) that will allow you to do this is [Azure Firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview). With this you can route all outbound traffic to the firewall and use its public IP for the outbound address.

[Azure vNet NAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-overview) is a new service that may help eventually, but at the moment it cannot be used across multiple vNets.